# Equivalence Classes of an Equivalence Relation Confusion (definition and solution included)

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

The Definition of Equivalence Classes of an Equivalence Relation is given as:
Suppose $A$ is a set and $R$ is an equivalence relation on $A$. For each element $a$ in $A$, the **equivalence class of a**, denoted $[a]$ is called the **class of a** for short, is the set of all elements $x$ in $A$ such that $x$ is related to $a$ by $R$. In symbols, it is $[a] = \{x \in A | xRa \}$. Hence, for all $x \in A$, $x\in[a] \iff xRa$.

Now let $A$ = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4} and define a relation $R$ on $A$ as follows:
$R$ = [(0, 0), (0,4), (1, 1), (1, 3), (2, 2), (3, 1), (3, 3), (4, 0), (4, 4)].

**Solution:**  First find the equivalence class of every element of $A$:

[0] = $ \{x \in A | xR0\} = \{0, 4\}$

[1] = $ \{x \in A | xR1\} = \{1, 3\}$

[2] = $ \{x \in A | xR2\} = \{2\}$

[3] = $ \{x \in A | xR3\} = \{1, 3\}$

[4] = $ \{x \in A | xR4\} = \{0, 4\}$

Note that [0] = [4] and [1] = [3]. Thus the distinct equivalence classes of the relation are:

**[0, 4], [1, 3], and [2]**.

**My Question is** Why isn't the following equivalence classes included as well:

[0] = $ \{x \in A | xR0\} = \{0\}$

[1] = $ \{x \in A | xR1\} = \{1\}$

[3] = $ \{x \in A | xR3\} = \{3\}$

[4] = $ \{x \in A | xR4\} = \{4\}$

Thank you so very much for your help and contributions. I am extremely grateful for your responses. Have a great day.

Comment: Why do you think $[0]=\{0\}$?

Comment: 0 is related to 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An equivalence class isn't just a set of things which are all equivalent to each other - it's a set of things which are all equivalent to each other, and which is **complete** in a sense: anything that you could put into the set, has been.

More precisely, the equivalence class of $x$ is the set of **all** $y$ which are equivalent to $x$ - so $\{0\}$ isn't an equivalence class because it's missing $4$. Does this make sense?

Comment: but what about [2] = {2}?

Comment: @gordonsung Is $2$ equivalent to anything other than itself?

Comment: There isn't. It is only equivalent to 2

Comment: @gordonsung That's why $\{2\}$ is an equivalence class.